# correct structure for django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following JSON response that I'm trying to store with django models. Each bet can have a number of items that have been wagered. In this case our user 'Nine' has place a bet with two items: 'Some Item Name' and 'Another Item Name'

```
 {'bet_id' : 234442288
 'user_id':  5554433
 'user_name': 'Nine'
 'item':    [{'name':   'Some Item Name',
             'item_id':  10,
             'rarity':  'Common'},
             {'name':   'Another Item Name',
              'item_id': 19,
              'rarity': 'Rare'}]
```

I have created two models, one for bet, and one for item.

```
class Bet(models.Model):
   bet_id = models.IntegerField()
   user_id = models.IntegerField()
   user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Item(models.Model):
   bet = models.ForeignKey(Bet)
   item_id = models.IntegerField()
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   rarity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

The goal is to be able to know exactly who has bet which items and to know how many items have been bet in total. The problem is however that I'm now storing many duplicate items. Items.objects.all() will now for example return ['Some Item Name', 'Some Item Name' , 'Another Item Name']. Is this an inefficient way or storing my data, and if so how can I improve upon it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote you `The goal is to be able to know exactly who has bet which items and to know how many items have been bet in total.`

For the second concern, of duplicated items, if you assume that there will same items that will be repeatedly bet over a period of time, you can probably try to separate Item model (remove foreign key from there) and have items as an M2M field in Bet model. By this what you can achieve is something as follows

- You can avoid duplication of items before creating them, by checking if they already exist.

You can probably think of changing your models to something like this

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rarity = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Bet(models.Model):
    bet_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

But this is based on assumption that **rarity** and **item_id** will always be same for an item.